# Front doesn't send anything

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I try to update a table, so I send new data from my front (Angular) to my back (Node). When I console.log the front everything is ok, but in back nothing happen.

But, my console validate my request (strange thing PUT /tournaments/update-status 200 79.748 ms - 2,
there is always this "- 2" at the end)

However,back works on Postman and I already used this method elsewhere in my project and it works perfectly.

Here is the code in my front :

```
updateParticipantStatus(participant){
    return this.http.put<Participant>(`${this.baseUrl}/tournaments/update-status`, participant)
    .subscribe(result => result);
}
```

And now the back :

````
  router.put('/update-status', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const participant: Participant = req.body;

    tournamentsService.updateParticipantStatus(participant).then(result => {
        res.send(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  });```

PS: Sorry for my bad english, if needed I can send more code.
````

Comment: what is the value of participant in updateParticipantStatus method? If thats not a string you can't append it to URL.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil Op isn't appending `participant` to the url, it's the payload for the request.

Comment: I would add a `.pipe` with a `.tap` and a `.catchError` before the `.subscribe` to make sure I'm seeing all errors.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil: participant is an object (id, comment, army_status)

Comment: @JDunken: Sorry can you explain where to put the .pipe, .tap and .catchError ?

Comment: Edit: It doens't work anymore on Postman :/

Comment: With the same code as above its not  working?

Comment: Replace `.subscribe(result => result);`  with `.subscribe(result => result, error=> {console.log(error)});` try this. You can see the error, if any, in console

Comment: Nothing more in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solve my problem.

I changed the adress from

```
router.put('/update-status', (req: Request, res: Response)
```

to

```
router.put('/update-status/:id', (req: Request, res: Response)
```

I don't understand why now it works but any way thanks @Ms.Tamil and @JDunken for the help.